# Criterion for multivariate convergence

Tags: probability, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I managed to prove that for some multivariate random variables $\textbf{X}\in\mathbb{R}^m$ that the convergence in distribution holds in finite-dimension:

$$(\textbf{X}_{t_1}^n,\cdots,\textbf{X}_{t_k}^n)\Rightarrow_n(\textbf{X}_{t_1},\cdots,\textbf{X}{t_k}).$$

I am now looking for a way to prove that $\textbf{X}^n\Rightarrow_n \textbf{X}$ under certain conditions.

For the one-dimensional case $X\in\mathbb{R}$ the results is given by Billingsley (1999), Theorem 13.5.

Does a similar result hold for the multi-dimensional case and where can I find it? (I imagine some similar arguement must have been used in the proof of the FCLT in multiple dimensions but cannot find a reference or result..)

Please help :)

Answer (score 1):

This is a somewhat vague question, so my answer sounds like Polonius's advice: similarly vague, but wordier.  There's two parts to your question area, I think.

First, are the scalar or finite dimensional distributions enough to specify the target distribution?  Here we have lots of tools, such as the easy part of the so-called [Wold's device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Wold_theorem) and the [Kolmogorov consistency theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_extension_theorem).  The former might be thought of as the mathematical basis for tomography: if for every fixed vector $a$ you know the distribution of the random scalar product $\langle a, X\rangle$, then you know the distribution of the vector $X$. (Which can be seen by inspecting the 1-dimensional slices thru the characteristic function of $X$, viz, $\varphi_{\langle a, X\rangle}(t)= \varphi_X(at)$.)  The latter, of course, is a tool for knowing that there are such things as random functions and random sequences involving infinitely many coordinates, when we start with knowledge of how finite collections of coordinates are behaving.

Second, do the random vectors or functions under study *have* limit behavior?  Here [Prokhorov's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prokhorov%27s_theorem) is central. The hard part in applying it often comes down to finding the correct scaling or centering (possibly combined with a non-linear transformation) so the scaled random vector becomes *tight*. In such cases you can often just read the answer off of the premises, once you've reached this far.  In other cases the difficulty involves checking tightness of the probability laws involved, which can require you to know a lot about the topology of the space containing your random elements, and in particular, about the compact sets that space.  For many spaces of functions or of sequences, compactness is related to oscillation or wiggliness of a given set of functions, which might be guaranteed by moment conditions of form $E[\sup_t |\partial X(\omega,t)/\partial t|^2]<\infty$, etc.

You seem to be interested in random functions of several variables.  Formally, you have to identify  a topological space to contain these functions, then identify the compact sets in that topology, then check tightness.  In practice this gets turned around  into recognizing the ways your functions oscillate, and finding  a topology for which these oscillations are typical, that is, with high probability contained in compact sets.  This is the pattern used in Billingsley's book again and again.  You can think of his book as a user's manual for Prokhorov's theorem.

Comment: Apologies, I realise now that my question is indeed a bit vague. What I am looking for is a tightness condition for the space of $m$-vectors of cadlag functions, $\mathbb{D}^m$ endowed with the metric $\max_{1\leq j\leq m}\{d_B(x_j,y_j)\}$ where $d_B$ denotes the Billingsley metric. I am looking for a tightness condition based on its moments similar to the one-dimensional condition stated in Theorem 13.5 in Billingsley. I hope this clears things up somewhat :)

Comment: And I, for giving such fatuous advice.  But in your case, isn't your topology on $\mathbb D^m$ just the product topology on the product of $m$ copies of $\mathbb D$, and hence the compact sets in the former are contained in the products of compacts in the latter, and so joint tightness follows separately from the $m$ componentwise tightness?